# Java - Add List<Double> to List<List<Object>>

Tags: java, list, object, double

I have a function that expects a List of Lists of Objects to fill the rows of a table, the type of data in each row needs to be Object, but when I try to add to the List of Lists a List of type Double, I get the following error

```
The method add(List<Object>) in the type List<List<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Double>)
```

Here an example:

```
List<List<Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

I'm guessing that autoboxing doesn't work when dealing with Objects inside a List.

How can I add the list of doubles to the list of lists of objects?
I can't modify the function that expects a List of List of objects to expect generic types, so really my question is how can I cast my list of Double to List of Objects without looping through the List and casting each item individually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: I don't know what you're asking - there doesn't seem to be a question in your question.  But I feel sure that if I did know, this question would be a duplicate of the one that OH GOD SPIDERS has identified.

Comment: What's your doubt or question here? Can you elaborate it

Comment: updated question!

Answer (score 3):

No, a List of doubles is not a list of objects..

You have to explicitly mention that List accepts any child class of the parent class.. in your case.. You have to do below to fix it..

```
    List<List<? extends Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(new ArrayList<Double>());
```

Comment: Yes but that list is not applicable for the function that expects a list of lists of objects